# How do you know if you're pregnant while on birth control?

Tags: obstetrics

How do you know if you're pregnant while taking take birth control? Also, is it possible to feel the symptoms of pregnancy after having sex earlier in the day?

Comment: I think it's best if your friend goes to a doctor to determine if she's pregnant or not

Comment: This really only needs simple research.

Answer (score 3):

You know by getting a pregnancy test. It can be a home test you buy in a pharmacy or you can visit a doctor or clinic.

No, it is not possible to feel symptoms of pregnancy mere hours after sex. It takes a week or two for the first signs to appear. A missed period is usually the first detectable sign.